# How to subtract a constant from a numpy array and then summing up the results?

Tags: python, numpy

How do one subtract a constant from every element in a list and then sum up the result in Python?
Code attached does not work:

```
an_array = np.array([2,4,6,5,8,10])
constant = np.mean(an_array)

result = np.sum(an_array - constant)
```

Comment: what value of result are you expected ?

Comment: `np.sum(an_array)-constant*an_array.size`?

Comment: @Qiu up to numerical errors, that is the same thing, and I don't think that your proposal is generally more numerically stable. Just check `a=np.random.rand(5);c=np.mean(a);np.sum(a-c);np.sum(a)-c*a.size` a few times, you will hit cases where the first results is zero and the second is not.

Comment: What is the point even of computing this with this constant? The result is known to be 0, up to numerical errors. `result = 0` would be my answer.

Comment: well the suggested solution does not work, unfortunately.

Comment: @endorphinus: I guess you have different problem, because your code and proposed code work just fine.

Comment: @Qiu, sorry I did not see the parenteses around an_array. Thank you!

Comment: @bers, yes it makes no sense to calculate it! Saw it in a paper, obviously it is some make up measure. Thanks for you input!

Comment: I'd love to see that paper ;)

Comment: @bers, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1309104215000136

Comment: @bers, ok! So how would you compute the PA in Python?

Comment: I need to correct myself - yes, this paper proposes computing PA as stated in your question. But unless $\bar{P}$ is defined as something which is not the mean of the $P_i$, they compute $0/0$. (For those without access to the paper, they compute $PA = \sum_i(P_i - \bar{P}) / \sum_i(O_i - \bar{O})$.) There is no need to compute that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.sum(an_array)-constant*an_array.size`

#### Edit 1:

I am a few seconds late as @Qui already pointed this solution out in the comments.